a new user registration process
I'm working on a project and need some guidance. When a new user registers with their email, I want to send an OTP to their respective email. After they verify the OTP, the user should be registered.
I have a doubt: Should I store the user info in a session and then send the OTP? If the OTP is verified, the user details are sent to the database and the user is registered. OR, should I create a separate table for the registration process in my database, and then, when the user verifies their OTP, store their data in the login table?
I'm confused about which approach to take, so please guide me.
I wan't which approach is better

Probably the question is more suited for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

It would be a opinion based answer, not suitable for this platform.
